# Accessing variables of of loaded swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm loading swf externally. I need to access it's methods and variables. This is the code I'm using:

```
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

var loader:Loader;
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("aaa.swf");
var mc:MovieClip;

createLoader();

function createLoader():void    {
    loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onSWFLoad);
    loader.load(req);
}

function onSWFLoad(e:Event):void    {
    mc = MovieClip(loader.content);
    addChild(mc);
    trace(loader.content)
}
```

`EM` is loaded SWF's document class. If questioned if variable `gameEnded` is declared publicly, the answer is yes. The game loads, but there is an error when calling the variable :

```
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property gameEnded not found on EM__Preloader__ and there is no default value.
    at main_fla::MainTimeline/onSWFLoad()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I had to embed all the code in SWF (I was using some TLF in it)

Answer (score 2):

Check your preloader setting in the ActionScript settings panel of your game.fla - `EM__Preloader__` looks to me like an auto-generated class (and *not* your main EM class).

Also, your EM class should implement a simple interface that you can cast your loader.content to (instead of MovieClip).  This way, you can be sure that the methods you need are available, and your code is type-safe.  Embed this interface into your preloader.fla instead of the EM class to prevent unnecessary bloating of your SWFs.

Comment: could you be a bit more descriptive about this embedding?

Comment: When you add `import my.package.MyClass;` to your script, the code for this class is compiled into your SWF - otherwise it won't be able to run.  An interface is considerably smaller than a class, because it provides only a "contract", a description of which methods can be called, instead of the actual implementation of these methods.  All your loader needs to access the "loadee"'s methods is an interface like that.  Check out this tutorial: http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/as3-101-oop-introduction-to-interfaces/

Comment: so i just should write `import EM;` ? it's in the same directory.

Comment: No, you should create an interface and import that.  Check out the tutorial!